# Putting fetched array into <a href> value in PHP

Tags: php, echo

I have a SQL query statement that will return a particular set of result. Such as ID, Names, Price. I have no problem with that.

However i am trying to add a  link within the echo loop and set ID as the value so that i can post it to another page. Would that be possible ?

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo
   "".$row{'Url'}."<br>"; 
   echo 
   "Name:".$row{'Name'}."<br>";
   echo
   "Price: $ ".$row{'Price'}."<br>";
   echo
   '<div class = "qwerty"  data-countdown= '.$row{'Time'}.'></div>';
   echo
   "Location:".$row{'Location'}."<br>";
   echo
   "Description:".$row{'Description'}."<br>";
echo   ''.$row{'ID'}.'';


echo '<a href="" onclick="jsScript()">Show Comments</a>
    <form id="displayComments" style="display:none" target="jsScript()" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="run" value=".$row{'ID'}." />
    </form>';
```

Comment: You are aware that in php you can access array content by $arrayName[$key] ?

Comment: Nope. I wasnt aware. Thanks for sharing, i will check that out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed quotes. `value="'.$row['ID'].'"`

`echo '<a href="" onclick="jsScript()">Show Comments</a> <form id="displayComments" style="display:none" target="jsScript()" method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="run" value="'.$row['ID'].'" /> </form>';`

And php array use [ ]

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: cheers mate. I get really bad with closing all the quotes when it gets really messy.